# merge two rows to one row with same ID sql db2

Tags: db2

I need help with below.

This is my Table:

Id      Out AccountNumber   Amount   Key

14587    2   32345678        458.00  Accepted
15672    7   12335678        095.00  Customer
15672    5   12345678        095.00  Description
17672    1   21345678        408.00  Accepted
15672    5   12345678        095.00  List
17672    1   12345678        408.00  Accepted

My desired output should be like:

Id          Out AccountNumber   Amount  Item1 Item2     Item3

14587    2   32345678   458.00  Accepted  NULL           NULL

15672    7  12335678    095.00  Customer  Description  List

17672    1  21345678    408.00  Accepted   Accepted    NULL

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Comment: Why don’t we see the row with id=17672 in the output?

Comment: @MarkBrainstein, I have updated desired output.

Comment: Id=15672 has different AccountNumbers. Is this typo or not?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, yeah It is typo. I’ve corrected that one.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein, yeah It is typo. I’ve corrected that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH TAB (ID, Out, AccountNumber, Amount, Key) AS 
(
VALUES
  (14587, 2, 32345678, 458.00, 'Accepted')
, (15672, 7, 12345678, 095.00, 'Customer')
, (15672, 5, 12345678, 095.00, 'Description')
, (17672, 1, 21345678, 408.00, 'Accepted')
, (15672, 5, 12345678, 095.00, 'List')
, (17672, 1, 21345678, 408.00, 'Accepted') 
)
*/
SELECT 
  MAX(ID) ID, MAX(Out) Out, AccountNumber
, MAX(Amount) AS Amount  
, MAX(CASE RN WHEN 1 THEN Key END) AS ITEM1
, MAX(CASE RN WHEN 2 THEN Key END) AS ITEM2
, MAX(CASE RN WHEN 3 THEN Key END) AS ITEM3
FROM
(
SELECT 
  ID, Out, AccountNumber, Amount, Key
, ROWNUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY Key) RN
FROM TAB
)
GROUP BY AccountNumber;
```

You may uncomment the commented out block and run the statement as is.